# Deep link onChange not triggered in SwiftUI sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue with deep links in my SwiftUI app.

In my app class I have declared deepLink as an environment variable for every View under ContentView() in the hierarchy:

```
...

@main
struct TestApp: App {

var userSettings: UserSettings
var dataFetcher: DataFetcher
var dataUpdater: DataUpdater

@State var deepLink = ""

init() {
    userSettings = UserSettings()
    dataFetcher = DataFetcher(userSettings: userSettings)
    dataUpdater = DataUpdater(userSettings: userSettings)
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
                .environmentObject(userSettings)
                .environmentObject(dataFetcher)
                .environmentObject(dataUpdater)
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    deepLink = url.absoluteString
                }
                .environment(\.deepLink, deepLink)
    }
}
```

}

In my ContentView() I've declared deepLink as an environment variable

```
struct ContentView: View {

    ...

    @State var isTestSheetViewPresented = false

    @Environment(\.deepLink) var deepLink: String

    ...

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.isTestSheetViewPresented = true
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                Text("Add")
                Spacer()
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isTestSheetViewPresented, content: {
            TestSheetView(isPresented: self.$isTestSheetViewPresented)
        })
        .onChange(of: self.deepLink) { _ in
            self.isTestSheetViewPresented = true
        }
    }

}
```

And the TestSheetView is like this

```
struct TestSheetView: View {

    @Environment(\.deepLink) var deepLink: String

    @State var url: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(url)
            .onChange(of: deepLink) { _ in
                if deepLink != "" {
                    self.url = deepLink
                }
            }
    }
```

}

The problem is that when I click on a link, and my app opens, the TestSheetView is correctly presented but the onChange is not triggered unless I scroll a little bit down the sheet.

Instead if I put the same code of the TestSheetView in the ContentView then the text is correctly shown

Comment: Seems like a timing issue. While `TestSheetView` is being initialized, the `body` is created _after_ `deepLink` changed, so it won't be able to detect it. The solution could be  you use `onAppear` in `TestSheetView` and read from there, or you pass in the `deepLink` from `ContentView`. Let me know if you want a full solution.

Comment: @George_E Ah yeah, it was a timing issue. Adding the onAppear() fixed it! If you want to  post the answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you - also just a small comment, rather than `deepLink != ""` it is better to use `!deepLink.isEmpty`. Not just for readability, but also performance, although the difference won't be massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a timing issue. While `TestSheetView` is being initialized, the body is created *after* `deepLink` changed, so it won't be able to detect it.

The solution is to use `onAppear` in `TestSheetView` and read from there, like so:

```
struct TestSheetView: View {

    @Environment(\.deepLink) var deepLink: String

    @State var url: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(url)
            .onAppear {
                if deepLink != "" {
                    self.url = deepLink
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unergonomic to handle both the case where the view is yet to appear, and the case where a link is being navigated within the view. The following view modifier handles both cases. It assumes an .onOpenURL() handler in the top level navigating view that sets both the current tab selection, along with the currentDeepLink environment value.

```swift
struct DeepLinkViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.currentDeepLink) private var currentDeepLink
    let action: ((URL) -> Bool)

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                if let url = currentDeepLink.wrappedValue,
                    action(url) {
                    currentDeepLink.wrappedValue = nil
                }
            }
            .onOpenURL { url in
                _ = action(url)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onDeepLink(perform action: @escaping ((URL) -> Bool)) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(DeepLinkViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

Use:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    @State urlString: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(urlString).onDeepLink { url
            self.string = url.absoluteString
            return true // return false if another handler should consume
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection: TabSelection = .something
    @State private var currentDeepLink: URL? = nil

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: self.$tabSelection) {
        ...
        }
        .onOpenURL { url in
             self.tabSelection = ... // determine selection from URL
             self.currentDeepLink = url
        }
        .environment(\.tabSelection, self.$tabSelection)
        .environment(\.currentDeepLink, self.$currentDeepLink)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. However, very smart solution!

Comment: FYI I did have some trouble getting this working reliably, sometimes both handlers would be called. In the end I found it best to handle the URL within the current tab. Also, you need to check whether the current view is presented and/or visible to avoid multiple onOpenURL handlers being fired.